# php redirect from /index.php to /

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I'm trying to get the browser to redirect whenever the user types in `/index.php` or `/index.php/` or `/index.php////` to just plain `/` . Here's what I have so far

```
if ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] == '/index.php') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'
}
```

But I get a infinite loop redirect error. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to make this work?

EDIT, it seems that changing `'ORIG_PATH_INFO'` to `'REQUEST_URI'` did the trick for `/index.php` what do I add to my `if` to take care of `index.php/` and `index.php////`...?

Comment: You redirect /index.php to / which means same thing

Comment: @safarov: yeah but it looks nicer in the url bar, and I need it for navigational reasons.

Comment: You can do it with .htaccess file too. If you want i can write a solution for u with htaccess

Comment: @safarov: sure but I need the rule to apply for subfolders too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REQUEST_URI`. When you use `ORIG_PATH_INFO`, you will always get `/index.php`.

Comment: I got the same issue with `REQUIEST_URI` which is why I thought that `ORIG_PATH_INFO` might work

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working now, is there any way to also check for index.php/ and index.php//// ...?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index.php[/]+$ / [L]` if you use RewriteEngine

Comment: Yes. `rtrim( $url, '/' )` (i.e. remove trailing slashes) before you check if it ends in index.php.

Answer (score 1):

base your condition on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead and when the url doesn't actually contain `index.php` it won't try and redirect.

and use `stristr` to search for `index.php` wherever it occurs in the url

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working now, is there any way to also check for `index.php/` and `index.php////` ...?

Comment: I guess for that I'd recommend using `stristr` to detect any url containing index.php or any variation of that http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: yeah but it could contain that in the query string

Comment: yes, of course -- if you first reduce the url string by loopping off as many characters as `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains, you can account for that